# Peek data in Serial port windows

Tags: windows, serial-port

How to know the data bytes availability at serail port in windows?
I mean, I just want to check whether serail port empty or not?

NOTE:
there was function in Linux "ioctl(fd,FIONREAD,&availableBytes)", I need to implement similar functionality in windows.

~ Johnnie

Answer (score 2):

This solved my problem:

Call the ClearCommError function and check the return in lpStat->cbInQue.

& I think it should solve yours too.

Refer windows api documentation for more clarification on ClearCommError() function.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In .Net the SerialPort class has a [BytesToRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.bytestoread.aspx) property.

Comment: I think he wants a Windows/C/API -type answer.

Answer (score 0):

ClearCommError is used to obtain error and stats info.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx